# Gekko, PWL function result is not as expected

Tags: python, gekko

The values of z are calculated in my original code, here I've
given them the values that were the result of such calculations
they look like `model.Equation(z[i] == someCalculation)` in my original code too.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
model = GEKKO(remote=False)

z = model.Array(model.Var,(3))
model.Equation(z[0] == 1e-5)
model.Equation(z[1] == 4)
model.Equation(z[2] == 5.99999)

z2 = model.Array(model.Var,(3))
for i in range(3):
    d = 1e-5
    x_data = [-1e5, 0, 0+d, 6]
    y_data = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    model.pwl(z[i], z2[i], x_data, y_data)
    
model.solve()
print(z)
print(z2)
```

I expect z2 to be `[[0] [1] [1]]`, but I get `[[0.99035520756] [0.97749877939] [0.97771605357]]`, z remains the same as it should. There might be an easier way to do what I'm trying to, but I would also like to understand why this approach yields this result.

Edit

Adding an objective function- like `model.Obj(model.sum(z2))` - seems to make it so the solver manipluated these variables too which is undesired to say the least. If the current setup is not capable of generating a solution I would like to see an error not the change of "fixed" variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect z2 to be `[[1],[1],[1]]` because the PWL output steps up from `0` to `1` between `0` and `+1e-5` (input). Here are some things to get closer to the solution:

- Try the `APOPT` solver with `m.options.SOLVER=1`. It is an active set solver instead of the default `IPOPT` solver that uses a barrier method. The active set solver tends to return more precise solutions, especially where a barrier term is involved in defining the solution.
- Use an integer variable for `z2` (with the `APOPT` solver). This also will help you find an integer solution, if that is a constraint.
- Use a tighter solution tolerance such as `m.options.RTOL=1e-9`. The default tolerance is `1e-6`. You may also need to adjust `m.options.OTOL` if you need a more precise objective function.

I switched the equation to `model.Equation(z[0] == -1e-5)` to show a solution of `[[0],[1],[1]]`

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
model = GEKKO(remote=False)

z = model.Array(model.Var,(3))
model.Equation(z[0] == -1e-5)
model.Equation(z[1] == 4)
model.Equation(z[2] == 5.99999)

z2 = model.Array(model.Var,(3)) #,integer=True)
for i in range(3):
    d = 1e-5
    x_data = [-1e5, 0, 0+d, 6]
    y_data = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    model.pwl(z[i], z2[i], x_data, y_data)

#model.options.RTOL = 1e-9
model.options.SOLVER = 1
model.solve()
print(z)
print(z2)
```

**Edit**

As you discovered, the PWL function uses slack variables. Including another objective can interfere with the correct PWL solution. The way to handle that is to may the relative objective of `model.Obj(model.sum(z2))` have a smaller gradient than the gradient of the PWL function. This is an example where `0.1*sum(z2)` is minimized and `0.01*sum(z)` is maximized.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
model = GEKKO(remote=False)

z = model.Array(model.Var,(3),value=1)

z2 = model.Array(model.Var,(3)) #,integer=True)
for i in range(3):
    d = 1e-5
    x_data = [-1e5, 0, 0+d, 6]
    y_data = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    model.pwl(z[i], z2[i], x_data, y_data)

# first most important objective is PWL (gradient = 1)

# second most important objective is to minimize z2 
model.Minimize(0.1*model.sum(z2))

# third most important objective is to maximize z
model.Maximize(0.01*model.sum(z))

model.options.SOLVER = 1
model.solve()
print(z)
print(z2)
```

This correctly gives the solution:

```
[[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
[[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
```

Alternatively, you can maximize `0.1*sum(z2)` and minimize `0.01*sum(z)` with:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
model = GEKKO(remote=False)

z = model.Array(model.Var,(3),value=1)

z2 = model.Array(model.Var,(3)) #,integer=True)
for i in range(3):
    d = 1e-5
    x_data = [-1e5, 0, 0+d, 6]
    y_data = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    model.pwl(z[i], z2[i], x_data, y_data)

# first most important objective is PWL (gradient = 1)

# second most important objective is to minimize z2 
model.Maximize(0.1*model.sum(z2))

# third most important objective is to maximize z
model.Minimize(0.01*model.sum(z))

model.options.SOLVER = 1
model.solve()
print(z)
print(z2)
```

to give:

```
[[1e-05] [1e-05] [1e-05]]
[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
```

I appreciate the warning message suggestion. However, it is generally too hard to find errors in models when the syntax is correct but there is a configuration that would lead to an undesirable solution. Hopefully your excellent question will help others with the PWL function.

Comment: This works but the second I add an objective function (such as model.sum(z2) ) or an equation involving values generated by the pwl those variables change to impossible values. What may be the cause of this? I added an edit mentioning this problem.

Comment: I accidentally tried to edit your answer instead of my question for that I apologise

Comment: No problem - it looks like other editors rejected the edit anyway.